# Json_Query Advice

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am trying to pick the value for the element "totalLoanBalance" but the `json_query` is retuning me a `null` value instead of giving me the value `34406.19`.

Can you please look at the query and advice what is the mistake I am making.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('{
    "balances": {
    "loanAcctBals": [
        {
        ----------
        ----------
        }
    ],
    "invAcctBals": [
        {
        ----------
        ----------
    ],
    "vestInfo": {
        ----------
        ----------
    },
    "vestPercents": [],
    "vestMessages": [],
    "balanceTotals": {
        "totalBalance": 42932.13,
        **"totalLoanBalance": 34406.19,**
        "totalInvBalance": 42932.13,
        "totalVestBalance": 0.0,
        "totalInvVestBalance": 0.0
    },
    "loanBalanceInd": "N",
    "isisMsgs": []
    },
"errorResponses": []
}', '$.totalLoanBalance') AS value
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Interesting that `json_query` in code became `jason_query` in the title. You get the null because root element does not have `totalLoanBalance` key. Please, check the [syntax rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618)

Comment: Can you please share me the link that has the information ?

Comment: I've updated my comment. Should be `$.balances.balanceTotals.totalLoanBalance`. Check with any online json path evaluator.

Comment: @astentx you're right - I was curious about this question and make this [dbfiddle sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0641534d1324b468151e77648d66fcd6).
You can consider post your answer and then the OP can accept it.

Comment: I have tried adding the $.balances.balanceTotals.totalLoanBalance WITH ARRAY WRAPPER and still it gives me null value.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar check the linked dbfiddle, there I used `WITH WRAPPER` - though I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Weird thing is if I remove some of the elements(invAcctBals,"vestInfo") i am getting the value. Could it be due to the alignment or spacing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to receive a SCALAR value, you will want to use `JSON_VALUE` instead of `JSON_QUERY`. `JSON_QUERY` will always return a JSON object or array. The query below will return the value you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE ('{
    "balances": {
        "loanAcctBals": [],
        "invAcctBals": [],
        "vestInfo": {},
        "vestPercents": [],
        "vestMessages": [],
        "balanceTotals": {
            "totalBalance": 42932.13,
            "totalLoanBalance": 34406.19,
            "totalInvBalance": 42932.13,
            "totalVestBalance": 0.0,
            "totalInvVestBalance": 0.0
        },
        "loanBalanceInd": "N",
        "isisMsgs": []
    },
    "errorResponses": []
}', '$.balances.balanceTotals.totalLoanBalance') AS VALUE FROM DUAL;
```